# Confusion about descriptive statistics in spss

Tags: spss, descriptive-statistics

I have bunch of variables i.e., *age*, *literacy level* (value 1 to 10), *gender* (`string` value of `M` or `F`). There is categorical variable called *promotion beyond specific grade* (value 1 or 0).

Now I want to do descriptive analysis on *age*, *literacy* and *gender* based on this categorical variable *promotion beyond specific grade*. The problem that I am seeing here is that *age* is a `scale` value, same goes for *literacy level*. but *gender* is a `string` value. So what should I do?

I was doing analysis like `Analyze` -> `Compare Means` -> `Means`. I was adding these 3 variables in "dependent" list and promotion variable in independent list. Is that correct approach?

P.S: I have already added a new variable called "sex" which is basically recoded from *gender* (M = 0 and F = 1). But again, this would become a categorical variable, so would it make sense to add this in dependent list?

A bit background: So for example in my country the high level execs (government execs) are level 19 and above. What I want to see if there is anything stands out for people who are level 19 and above or not. I am using age, literacy level (masters, undergrad etc) and gender to analyze this. this is the first step in lots of other calculations that i'd be doing. But for this i am kind of confuse that how to use gender. (this is part of assignment where we are asked to use gender but to me its not making sense in this case since it has only string value of M and F)

Comment: You need to tell us what is your goal, what do you want to learn from the data? And, specifically, what do *promotion beyond specific grade* represent? It is not clear to me what it means!

Comment: So for example in my country the high level execs (government execs) are level 19 and above. What I want to see if there is anything stands out for people who are level 19 and above or not. I am using age, literacy level (masters, undergrad etc) and gender to analyze this. this is the first step in lots of other calculations that i'd be doing. But for this i am kind of confuse that how to use gender. (this is part of assignment where we are asked to use gender but to me its not making sense in this case since it has only string value of `M` and `F`)

Comment: Please add this as an edit to the question itself ... commenta here are ephemeral, and many people do not read them!

Comment: Just added this to main question but it doesn't change the essence of question i.e., for descriptive statistics should i use `string` based value of `gender`? or should i use some other way to do so?